# Ruby on rails .order and sort by multiple models in one method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote this code to build a sort of "ranking system" to show which users have the most MCQ's in the past 10 days. Now, there are more models that have to be tracked as part of this "ranking" system, and I'm wondering how that can be done.

I've tried appending .joins for each of the pluralized model names, but that doesn't do anything.

```
def leaderboard_count
    User.joins(:multiple_choice_questions)
        .joins(:verbal_questions)
        .group('users.id')
        .where('multiple_choice_questions.created_at >= ?', 10.days.ago.utc)
        .order('count(multiple_choice_questions.id) desc')
        .limit(5)
end
```

I've tried searching for more info about .order as a method, but it's only helpful for one model at a time and its attribute. If I have `Post` and `MultipleChoiceQuestion` as two models, then the goal is to get the total number of posts + MCQs and show that.

Thanks in advance for any tips or help.

Edit - this is my view code.

```
<% leaderboard_count.each do |x| %>

    <%= "#{x.first_name} #{x.last_name[0]}" %>

    <%= x.multiple_choice_questions.where("created_at >= ?", 10.days.ago.utc).count %>
    <%= x.verbal_questions.where("created_at >= ?", 10.days.ago.utc).count %>


<% end %>
```